# How can I distinguish between Fedora and Ubuntu?

Tags: javascript

I already know how to know my OS is linux.

```
navigator.userAgent.indexOf('X11')
```

But Ubuntu and Fedora has same navigator.userAgent so I can't distinguish it.

What property contains that information?

Comment: Strictly speaking, checking for X11 doesn't tell you that the OS is Linux, just that the browser is using the X Window System.  X11 *can* be used on Windows and Mac too; it's just not typical.

Comment: Something sent to the server might - that's evidently how pages detect which download you want. What serverside language are you using?

Comment: In addition to what Wyzard says, it's also the other way around: Linux *need not* use X11. One example is Android, which is technically running on a Linux kernel, but doesn't use the X11 display system.

Comment: @Wyzard Thank you for your advice and I will change my code more strictly.

Comment: @JamWaffles My serverside language is php but I have to detect it with only javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to reliably tell what distribution the user is running through the user agent string. Sometimes you want even be able to detect if it's Linux or not.

If you look at the [Gecko user agent string specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_user_agent_string_reference), you'll see no reference to including the Linux distribution in the UA string.

It would be far more reliable to just ask your users what distro they're running.

Answer (score 1):

Look for `Fedora` and `Ubuntu` in the same useragent strings

`Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.14) Gecko/20080612 Fedora/2.0.0.14-20080612.fc8.acer Firefox/2.0.0.14`

`Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; sv-SE; rv:1.8.1.12) Gecko/20080207 Ubuntu/7.10 (gutsy) Firefox/2.0.0.12`

But I would recommend that don't bank on the UA strings, you may or may not be able to identify completely all of the incoming requests.

Comment: The latest Firefox on Ubuntu 11.04 *doesn't* send the `Ubuntu/11.04` string, while the latest Chromium *does*. So yes: it's *not* reliable at all.

Comment: navigator.userAgent in my feodra is 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2'. It doesn't contain string for distinguishing.