# Detect distro of linux and release version of distro (javascript - client side)

Tags: javascript, linux, ubuntu, frontend, user-agent

I'm trying to find out the distro of Linux the user is using and the release version of that particular distro. For other OS like Windows, macOS, iOS, and Android you could easily find it out through parsing the userAgent string. But on Linux, it seems to be [not that easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644912/how-can-i-distinguish-between-fedora-and-ubuntu). I tried out testing on ubuntu, seems like some browsers don't set the userAgent string with `Ubuntu`.

It would be helpful to know if there is some [other way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/appVersion) to find out at least the distro of the user accurately on the client-side using JS.